# Crm 2011 Getting time from DateTime field on form

Tags: javascript, forms, datetime, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm having trouble getting the hour and minute portions from the datetime field on the form.

```
var date = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("createdon").getValue();
```

I can use getDate(), getMonth() and GetFullYear() methods on the returned object, but I cannot get the hour and minute data. The date object shows "Tue Dec 25 11:47:44 UTC+0200 2012", so the time is there. Is the only way to get hour/minute to do some ugly substring operations on that value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use *getHours* and *getMinutes* on the *Date* object.

```
var date = new Date();
var time = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();
```

Now, you only need to substitute the value for *date* as it in my example is the current point of time and you're fetching it from a field.

---

You might want consider shortening your syntax as well. I'm not in front of the computer at the moment (not **that** computer, that is), but I believe that you can go like this instead.

```
var date = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("createdon").getValue();
```

It's amazing - no matter how much JavaScript one codes. Five minutes later, everything is gone from the mind. It's like if the syntax is intended to be memory resistant. :)

---

You should **not** be playing around with *substring* nor *regex*. JavaScript source code tends to be ugly and confusing the way it is already. No point making it worse and less comprehensible.

And as for the regular expressions - a programmer had a problem to solve. So he thought - "I know, I'll use *RegEx*". Then he had **two** problems.

Comment: Removed my previous comment, I was doing something wrong. Thank you, works great!

Comment: @user1243675 Just for the fullness of my reply - if the problem sustains (or reappears), you can check that the *Date* object you're creating is really an instance of *Date* class. It could happen that you have a string (looking just like the date) and need to **create** an actual *Date* object from it in order to get to it's methods. In this case, however, I didn't think that because you got the other methods (*getYear* and what not). Glad it worked! Also, you might consider changing your nick name - it's not very personal at the moment. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var DateTimeFormatString ="hh:MM:ss";
     // Formats the date to CRM format
        function dateToCRMFormat(date) {
            return dateFormat(date, DateTimeFormatString );
        }


// Formats the date into a certain format
function dateFormat(date, format) {
    var f = "";

    try {
        f = f + format.replace(/dd|mm|yyyy|MM|hh|ss|ms|APM|\s|\/|\-|,|\./ig,
        function match() {
            switch (arguments[0]) {
                case "dd":
                    var dd = date.getDate();
                    return (dd < 10) ? "0" + dd : dd;
                case "mm":
                    var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
                    return (mm < 10) ? "0" + mm : mm;
                case "yyyy": return date.getFullYear();
                case "hh":
                    var hh = date.getHours();
                    return (hh < 10) ? "0" + hh : hh;
                case "MM":
                    var MM = date.getMinutes();
                    return (MM < 10) ? "0" + MM : MM;
                case "ss":
                    var ss = date.getSeconds();
                    return (ss < 10) ? "0" + ss : ss;
                case "ms": return date.getMilliseconds();
                case "APM":
                    var apm = date.getHours();
                    return (apm < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
                default: return arguments[0];
            }
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
    }

    return f;
}
```

For testing

```
var time= Xrm.Page.getAttribute("createdon").getValue();
 alert("Time: " + dateToCRMFormat(time));
```